# from pubnub import Pubsub ImportError: cannot import name Pubnub

Tags: raspbian, python

This might be a possible duplicate, but I wasn't able to find a solution in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354575/importerror-cannot-import-name-pubnub). I am new to raspberry Pi I wish to use Pubnub to communicate with an android application and a Raspberry Pi. I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B with a freshly installed Raspbian OS.

I followed the initial steps from [here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-27-internet-of-things-101-getting-started-w-raspberry-pi/).

- Install Python:

  ```
  pi@raspberrypi ~$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
  ```
- Install pip:

  ```
  pi@raspberrypi ~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
  ```
- Install PubNub:

  ```
  pi@raspberrypi ~$ sudo pip install pubnub
  ```

then I wrote the exact code and saved it as hello.py with my publish and subscription keys:

```
import sys
from pubnub import Pubnub

pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key='<your-pub-key>', subscribe_key='<your-sub-key>')

channel = 'hello-pi'

data = {
  'username': 'Your name',
  'message': 'Hello World from Pi!'
}

def callback(m):
  print(m)

pubnub.publish(channel, data, callback=callback, error=callback)
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pubnub import Pubnub
ImportError: cannot import name Pubnub
```

Cannot find a solution and it is a very annoying error this early in my project. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from `pubnub import pubnub` or from `pubnub.pubnub import PubNub`

there seems to have been a change in version 4.

The documentation for version 4.0.4, which is what I just installed via pip can be found [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk-v4) (including a cut and paste example).

You can verify which version is installed using the following command:

```
pip show pubnub
```

Comment: Now I am gettinh this error:TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subscribe_key'

Comment: Did you change your code to match the version of the library I linked to? If so that is a different question. Do not combine multiple questions especially don't add them in the comments. And please include the full error text.

Comment: i made this change : pubnub.pubnub import PubNub and now the previous error is replaced by "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subscribe_key' ". I checked the sdk version and it is 4.0.4. Thereafter I followed the link you mentioned copy pasted the examples. Although the code is working now but the code is complex for a beginner. Thank anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`pip install 'pubnub>=3,<4'`

Because Pubnub Released their V4 which is a bit advanced , the example code given works with V3 as mentioned in https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk-v3

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem... turned out that i was missing apt-get update. So i did a fresh installation

```
pip uninstall pubnub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
sudo pip install pubnub
```

As of now, this will install pubnub latest version => 4, so you need to import it like this

```
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
```

Answer (score 0):

For me below has solved the problem
I am using Python 2.5.7 version. Type below on terminal window:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python

import sys

sys.path

sys.path.append('Path_to_your_pubnub_library')
```

Comment: I think you might have had a typo in the last line; you wrote `sys.path.apend` but I'm guessing you meant to write `sys.path.append`. I've edited to fix that; if you want to change anything else you can [edit] further.

Answer (score -1):

Install pubnub version 3.9.0 using

```
$sudo pip install pubnub==3.9.0
```

it works fine..!

Comment: Could you give some kind of explanation to your solution?